# How to properly setup a DataSource in IntelliJ for DB2 stored procedures usage?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, db2

I have a problem with IntelliJ integration with DB2.
We have a Spring Boot application that uses MyBatis mappers to call procedures. It doesn't have any specific configuration, just plain URL + username + password.

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:db2://ip:port/db_name
    username: ...
    password: ...
    driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

DB2 procedure doesn't have OUT params, only single IN.
I am able to call it not only as the MyBatis mapper query, but plain old JDBC `PreparedStatement` etc.
However, when trying to call the same procedure in IntelliJ, while using the same driver+license, the same user, the same url, db, etc., I receive an error:

`SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=PROCEDURE;MY_PROCEDURE, DRIVER=4.28.11`

According to this doc https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=sec-440 there might be these causes:

1. **The routine name was either incorrectly specified or does not exist in the database.** -- It definitely exists and I'm able to call it via JDBC in Java code.
2. **A qualified reference was used, and the schema qualifier was incorrectly specified.** -- When using JDBC, regardless of the schema being set, it executes as expected. The query itself contains that schema `CALL {SCHEMA}.{MY_PROCEDURE}('test');`. Apart from that, it doesn't matter which schema is chosen in the SQL session when using IntelliJ (either `SET schema USER` or `SET schema {SCHEMA}`)
3. **The user's SQL path does not contain the schema to which the function belongs, and an unqualified reference was used.** -- This remains unclear, actually. Any additional clarifications are welcome...
4. **The wrong number of arguments was included.** -- Not in this case
5. **The right number of arguments was included in the routine reference, but the data type of one or more of the arguments is incorrect.** -- Not in this case either
6. **The invoker of the routine is not authorized to execute the routine.** -- I couldn't find any difference between JDBC connection configuration and IntelliJ DataGrip one.

So, possibly, cause #3 is the one that restricts me from calling the procedure, but how could I fix that?

Comment: This seems to be a problem determination question, not a programming question. You have a working case, and a failing case. Compare the output of `select current path from sysibm.sysdummy1` for both cases (if all other factors are identical as you say). If that yields no differences, compare the jdbc trace output for both cases. Refer to docs for enabling jdbc trace.

Comment: `current path` is also identical. Thank you, will try to trace then and get back

Comment: Ok, I see that IntelliJ makes `Connection.createStatement()`, then `Statement.execute("CALL {SCHEMA}.{MY_PROCEDURE}('test');")`, and while making the same manually via JDBC, I get the same error. No error when using `Connection.prepareWhatever("...")`. Is there a way to configure JDBC driver usage in IntelliJ for these calls?

Comment: When the target database-server is Db2-for-Z/OS, stored procedures that have input parameters can only be invoked by a preparedStatement (and otherwise will return the -440 code).. You need to open a ticket with the provider of Intellij to check if they have a way to handle this, or otherwise use a different development gui that correctly understands Db2-for-Z/OS.

Comment: Or use the CallableStatement interface

Comment: For people having the same issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-19251 is the bug report to follow.